# Flask session attribute loses typing after initial load

Tags: python, session, flask

Flask's `session` object appears to be changing an `OrderedDict` into a `dict`. This matters because I had hoped to store information regarding the current user's accessible pages in an `OrderedDict` to assist with automating the creation of the navigation bar.

I could be sleepy-eyed but I don't think I've written anything here that would overwrite existing data, so AFAICT it just converts to `dict` for no apparent reason.

Here's the code that sets the `OrderedDict` in the `session` object.

```
def safe_route(page_request):
    """Returns the correct page for the user's request.

    If a user requests a non-existent page, 404.
    If user wants a page they shouldn't see, but somehow
    they know about it, redirects to an access-denied page.

    If everything is in order, returns the page the user requests.
    """
    if page_request not in ordered_urls:
        return abort(404)      # early return for 404s

    # get current user and build their navi-dict.
    # this dict will be used to build the navibar in the webpage.
    if not 'registered' in session:
        CurrentUser = get_user(request)
        session['name'] = CurrentUser.name
        session['navi'] = build_user_navi(CurrentUser)
        session['registered'] = True
    if page_request in session['navi']:
        tpl = "/{}.html".format(page_request)
    else:
        # if here, the user requested a page that DOES exist
        # but they do NOT have access to. therefore, they are being
        # goons and require a trip to boxxytown
        tpl = "accessdenied.html"
    return render_template(tpl, on_page=page_request)
```

It checks to ensure that the session has the `'registered'` flag; if not it gets the user information and then calls `build_user_navi` which returns the `OrderedDict`. This works the first time; the initial page load shows the links in the navibar as I originally intended. Upon subsequent clicking around, the order is lost and apparently so is the type on the `OrderedDict`.

Before the `render_template` call, I added this line in the code to see if it was just changing types on me:

```
print type(session['navi'])
```

Sure enough, it switches between `<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>` and `<type 'dict'>`.

Is there a method for correctly storing an `OrderedDict` as session data, or is there some Perfectly Good Reason why this would only work the first time which should dissuade me from this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All data in the session needs to be JSON serializable.  An `OrderedDict` is serializable because it is a subclass of `dict`, but there is no ordered dict in JSON, so you lose order during serialization.

You can override [how Flask serializes the session](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/0.10.1/flask/sessions.py#L55) in order to support ordered dicts.  It's not the most convenient process, since you have to copy the code for the class.

```
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from collections import OrderedDict
from datetime import datetime
import uuid
from flask import json
from flask._compat import text_type, iteritems
from flask.debughelpers import UnexpectedUnicodeError
from markupsafe import Markup
from werkzeug.http import http_date, parse_date


class TaggedJSONSerializer(object):
    def dumps(self, value):
        def _tag(value):
            if isinstance(value, tuple):
                return {' t': [_tag(x) for x in value]}
            elif isinstance(value, uuid.UUID):
                return {' u': value.hex}
            elif isinstance(value, bytes):
                return {' b': b64encode(value).decode('ascii')}
            elif callable(getattr(value, '__html__', None)):
                return {' m': text_type(value.__html__())}
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                return [_tag(x) for x in value]
            elif isinstance(value, datetime):
                return {' d': http_date(value)}
            elif isinstance(value, OrderedDict):
                return {'OrderedDict': [[k, _tag(v)] for k, v in iteritems(value)]}
            elif isinstance(value, dict):
                return dict((k, _tag(v)) for k, v in iteritems(value))
            elif isinstance(value, str):
                try:
                    return text_type(value)
                except UnicodeError:
                    raise UnexpectedUnicodeError(u'A byte string with '
                        u'non-ASCII data was passed to the session system '
                        u'which can only store unicode strings.  Consider '
                        u'base64 encoding your string (String was %r)' % value)
            return value
        return json.dumps(_tag(value), separators=(',', ':'))

    def loads(self, value):
        def object_hook(obj):
            if len(obj) != 1:
                return obj
            the_key, the_value = next(iteritems(obj))
            if the_key == ' t':
                return tuple(the_value)
            elif the_key == ' u':
                return uuid.UUID(the_value)
            elif the_key == ' b':
                return b64decode(the_value)
            elif the_key == ' m':
                return Markup(the_value)
            elif the_key == ' d':
                return parse_date(the_value)
            elif the_key == 'OrderedDict':
                return OrderedDict(the_value)
            return obj
        return json.loads(value, object_hook=object_hook)
```

Here's a demonstration of the new tag in action.  The OrderedDict is deserialized correctly.

```
s = TaggedJSONSerializer()
data = OrderedDict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate('abcd'))
print(data)  # OrderedDict([('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 3)])
data = s.dumps(data)
print(data)  # {"OrderedDict":[["a",0],["b",1],["c",2],["d",3]]}
data = s.loads(data)
print(data)  # OrderedDict([('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 3)])
```

Then tell your app to use this serializer.

```
app.session_interface.serializer = TaggedJSONSerializer()
```

Comment: The JSON serialization is the key here - excellent answer. This is a lot of code for a navigation bar, so I'll probably actually go with the other poster's recommendation of using a different container, but I *really* like this

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that session object is deep-copied somewhere, and the `OrderedDict` gets copied as a plain `dict`. This can be found out by e.g. consulting the source.

The simplest fix I'd come up with is to store a plain list of key-value pairs instead of an `OrderedDict`, which is about as easy to iterate over and is easy to convert to any king of `dict` should you need repeated fast lookup.

Comment: Oh man, I just refactored around `dicts` haha. welp that'll teach me to try new things.